# How to get Highest and Lowest Latitude and Longitude from mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of addresses and I'm setting up a map search option on my website. The database has data such as address, price, numberOfBedrooms, numberOfBathrooms, Latitude, Longitude, etc. A user has the option to search by City and Price. Once a user clicks the search button I construct my sql query and return the results. How can I get the latitude and longitude range in 4 separate variables (ie. Highest Lat, Lowest Lat, Highest Long, and Lowest Long) in order to set the boundaries for google maps?

mysql query example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE City = "city" AND Price BETWEEN "100000" AND "200000"
```

Let's say it returned 50 results. Would it be more efficient to do more sql queries to find the min and max lat/lng coordinates, or is there a way to loop through the results to find the min/max lat/lng using only one query that would be quicker?

EDIT: I should point out that I also need it to return all the other columns as well as the highest and lowest lat/lng

Comment: Are `lat` and `lng` in two columns, or one comma-separated `latlng` string?

Comment: lat and lng are in two separate columns

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in MySQL < 8 like this:

```
SELECT id, price, lat, lng, maxlat, minlat, maxlng, minlng
FROM places
FULL  JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(lat) maxlat, MIN(lat) minlat, MAX(lng) maxlng, MIN(lng)          
            minlng FROM places) a
WHERE price BETWEEN 100 AND 250
```

This would set the bounds to the full dataset. If you wanted the bounds to be within the result set you would need to copy the `WHERE` conditions into the subquery. This requires two scans of the table so you need to determine if this is efficient in your case.

With MySQL version 8 you can define the query once and scan the results as follows:

```
WITH myQuery AS
(SELECT id, price, lat, lng
FROM places
WHERE price BETWEEN 100 AND 250)

SELECT * FROM myQuery FULL JOIN (SELECT Max(lat), MIN(lat), MAX(lng), MIN(lng) FROM myQuery) a
```

This is probably the most efficient SQL-based solution.

Otherwise you can do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id, price, lat, lng
FROM places
WHERE price BETWEEN 100 AND 250");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $maxLng = (!isset($maxLng) || $result['lng'] > $maxLng) ? $result['lng'] : $maxLng;
     //etc..
}
```

This would be the most efficient if you are already looping over your results as part of your existing code, which I suspect you are.

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67ff6UpKC2YT5yFudrZZH3/0

Comment: That last solution is perfect. I am already looping through each result to display the listings. Thanks